# Blue screen of death and system restore

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Whenever I boot my computer, a white line appears on top of the screen after Windows loads. Blue screen then appears and the computer restarts automatically. After that, it goes straight to system restore and then I can use my computer normally.

I've tried changing the hard drive thinking it was the problem but the problem still persists even after changing.

I attached a link to my Youtube video for your reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZp0zBVm4Co

- White line: 0:37 ~ 0:39
- Blue screen: 0:43 ~ 0:46

PC Specs:

- OS: Windows 7 ultimate (64bit)
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo E4500 @2.20GHz
- Video card: NVIDIA Geforce GT 430
- RAM: 4GB
- Motherboard: G31M-ES2C

Comment: Boot into safe mode and see what happens. The issues seems to be with NVIDIA device driver based on the nvlddmkm.sys BSOD from the video. Try installed older or newer version of NVIDIA drivers. Pull out the graphics card if you plugged on in and that's a change and use the built-in video instead until you determine what the incompatibility issue is with the NVIDIA device driver. Do some Google searching on "*NVIDIA nvlddmkm.sys BSOD Windows 7*" too. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  tried to install an older version of the driver and for some reason, no more bsod. Will update again tomorrow just to be sure

Comment: Based on the bugcheck code see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x116---video-tdr-error

Comment: I am no longer experiencing the error. Thanks guys!